# How to change string value label

Tags: variables, label, stata

Suppose I have a string variable that takes on several string values:

```
gen rand = runiform()
sort rand
gen var1 = ""
replace var1 = "A" if rand < .3
replace var1 = "B" if rand>=.3 & rand < .7
replace var1 = "C" if var1==""
```

How would I change the values of var1?  For example, `A` to be `Aaa`, `B` to be `Bbb`, and `C` to be `Ccc`?

I want to do something like the following (but rather replace the variables), which I know is incorrect:

```
label define var1L "A" "Aa" B "Bbb" C "Ccc"
label values var1 var1L
```

Comment: The key confusion is removed by considering the explanation of `label define`: ... defines a list of ...  associations of integers and text called value labels.  http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String variables can't have value labels. You can interpret this as if labels for string variables are meant to be the content of the variable itself. But you can `replace`:

```
clear
set more off

input ///
str1 var1
A
B
C
end

list

replace var1 = "Aaa" if var1 == "A"
replace var1 = "Bbb" if var1 == "B"
replace var1 = "Ccc" if var1 == "C"

list
```

You need to say more about your data and objectives for a more useful answer.

Comment: That was easy...and I feel dumb for not thinking of `replace`.  I was thinking in terms of value labels and couldn't figure it out.  This is all I needed.  Thank you kindly.

Comment: No problem. You might want to `generate` a new variable and do `replace` with that one so you can keep the original variable without changes. An alternative is to convert those strings into numbers using `encode`, add value labels, and work with those from then on. Some data management operations are just more conveniently done when the variable is numeric.